# Fastest way to sort in Ms sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

I have two large databases(2.7 million entries each) which need to be merged and sorted .
The sorting of merged table consumes a lot of time when done by order by.
Is there any other way to sort this merged table faster?
I have already tried indexing which speeds up the execution but i'm looking for more speed
If anyone can help.Thanks

Comment: Sorted when? Why would you need to extract 2.7 million rows together in one go except if its for a dump?

Comment: Need some more details.

Comment: sorting is very costly within SQL. Couple of questions; Why do you need this data sorted? And can you do this in your application layer?

Comment: I need to display all the entries

Comment: The data conatins a field that is the date ..and all the results need to be sorted by date...i dont exactly know what is sorting  in application layer.If you could guide me .Thanks a lot

Comment: The only way to sort data in sql is using order by. If you have 5.4 million records, sorting them will take time, no way around it. You might want to consider paging, since displaying that amount of records to a human is insane.

Comment: Fastest way is - not to sort. Get it already sorted if possible: read nonclustered index, alter clustered index. If you are merging 2.7M - optimize your tempdb, add more RAM. Or do it by pieces if possible. If you are merging I suppose this means scans of both sides.

Answer (score 4):

1. Have clustered index on the sort column `[date]` to pre-order the data in each table.
2. Create indexed view on the query with primary key on `([date], id)`. That would effectively create merged table maintained automatically by RDBMS engine.
3. Add more RAM, Cores, faster SSDs for tempdb etc.

**Update** following comments on approach 1. Basing on this query:

```
Select *
From table1
Inner Join table2 On table1.id=table2.id
Order By table1.[date]
```

`table2` having `id` for the primary key does not require any additional indexes.

`table1` would benefit from

```
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX idx_table1_date ON table1 ([date])
INCLUDE ( ...all other fields except id which is included anyway... );
--... so that all the select data is available from the index without another lookup by PK
```

That would effectively create a copy of `table1` pre-sorted by date. As the result query would scan `idx_table1_date` and lookup `table2` by primary key.

Comment: My query is like :Select * from table1 inner join table2 on table1.id=table2.id  order by date DESC ...I have created clustered index on primary key(id) of both tables .Should any other index be created?

Comment: Which table the date is coming from?

Comment: I'm performing inner join on data from table1 and table2. Both contain the date column

Comment: OK, but two records with matching `id` from two different tables can have different `date` values. Which `date` do you have in `ORDER BY` expression?

Comment: Speaking of the sorting I have completely messed the order! Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

It depends much on your actual columns but you should try to optimize the indexes even further for this query. Properly placed indexes should speed it up, but you have got to realize it's still a bunch of data and sorting is a pain in SQL Server.

You might want to check [this link](http://sqlperformance.com/2014/08/sql-indexes/considerations-indexes-and-sorts) for some tips.